# Cypress get the length of a row without having any table body

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I have the following code from the picture and the website, how can I make an assertion that the row has a 4 length?
And how i say in the tittle , it is not a table body :(

Thank you!!!

```
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqbfA.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLL74.jpg
```

Comment: It is more helpful to provide the code directly than links to images of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a list, you will get the length of all `li` elements in one go. The best I could think of, that you can do is, get all the list elements and then make assert that that the `total length %4 == 0`. Which will mean no matter how many rows are there all the rows will have 4 elements. Something like

```js
cy.get('li[id*="screenshot"]')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    cy.wrap(len % 4).should('eq', 0)
  })
```